# Audio QAM Transceiver Problems GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio, transceiver, audio

I'm learning radio techniques and am building transceivers for different modulation methods in GNU Radio. I am trying to develop a 16 QAM transceiver but I am having a huge amount of issues getting a clean constellation from my input into the modulation block. I'm not looking for specific help just if anyone can see any clear issues with my setup having some pointers would be amazing, as I cant find anything useful online for my specific case.
[image]

If I bypass all the QAM modulation stuff I can get audio through, and looking at other QAM modulators that use random sources I have set up my constellation object correctly for 16 QAM. Any more info thats needed I can update, sorry if my format is off or if this has been answered somewhere and I have missed it! Below is the output:

[image]